# Why for $\psi$ square-integrable function the zero mean condition is equivalent to $\hat{\psi}(0) = 0$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

I am studying the classical book "Ten Lectures on Wavelets" written by Ingrid Daubechies and I do not understand a specific point. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with detailed explication and new references to my study:

Let $\psi(t)$ be a square-integrable function that satisfies the zero mean condition: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(t) \, dt=0$. There is an implicit affirmation (please, see the fragment of the Daubechies book) that the zero mean condition to $\psi(t)$ implies that $\hat{\psi}(0)=0$ (here, $\hat{\psi}(t)$ is the Fourier Transform of the $\psi$ function). Why this is true? Can I demonstrate this? Besides, how are these conditions implied in Equation 2.4.1? I am a little confused about these connections.

[Fragment of "Ten Lectures on Wavelets"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxp07.png)

Comment: For an $L^1$ function this is clear from the definition of the Fourier transform: $\hat{\psi}(0) = \int e^{-ix\cdot 0} \psi(x)dx = 0$. For an $L^2$ function you can extend this fact by a straightforward approximation argument.

Comment: @kieransquared I think there has to be some tacit regularity or integrability assumption already on $\psi$. Point evaluations are not well-defined on elements of $L^2(\widehat{\mathbb R})$, so to even speak of $\widehat{\psi}(0)$ some extra assumption/conditions are needed.

Comment: @kieransquared thanks a lot! When I read your short message I can understand. Regards!

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks. I will search for concepts of regularity and approximation arguments to understand how Equation 2.4.1 can be derived from the mean zero condition.

Comment: @YemonChoi You’re absolutely right. $\psi\in L^1\cap L^2$ should be enough.

Comment: The claim in the excerpted [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxp07.png) asserts the equivalence $\hat\psi(0) = 0 \iff \int \psi(x)\mathrm dx = 0$ only for $\psi \in L^1$ (although the surrounding context suggests that we also mean to assume that $\psi \in L^2$).

Comment: A nonsense(?) answer.... Plancherel's theorem yields $$\int \psi(t)\;dt = \langle\psi,1\rangle= \langle\widehat{\psi},\delta\rangle = \widehat{\psi}(0),$$ since $\hat{1} = \delta$.  But Plancherel is for $L^2$ functions, and neither $1$ nor $\delta$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.